# If checkboxes are checked angularjs using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my HTML

```
    <div ng-controller="Orders">
        <div ng-repeat="order in orders">
          <form>
            <div ng-repeat="item in order.line_items">
                <input type="checkbox" name="order_{{order.id}}_items[]"?> {{item.name}}
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
app.controller("Orders", function($scope, WC) {
    var Woocommerce = WC.WC();
    // get orders from json
    Woocommerce.get('orders?filter[post_status]=wc-processing&?filter[limit]=-1', function(err, data, res){
        var obj = JSON.parse(res);
        console.log(obj.orders);
        $scope.orders = obj.orders;
        $scope.$apply()
    });

});`
```

It outputs this:

[image]

Per order I want to know true false if any of the order items has been checked so I can then show a submit button.

On the checkboxes I have tried `ng-repeat` and `ng-model` with no success so far.

Comment: can you paste a sample json output that you aare getting from woocommerce

Comment: I feel the woocommerce json data is irrelevant. I just need something in the controller to know if any of the check boxes are checked at all and if so then show a button.

Comment: only when we look at the data which you are assigning to your orders variable , then can we try helping

Comment: If you look at the JSON response in the documentation you can see teh type of data I am receiving: http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-orders

Comment: Set the checkbox input ng-model="item.isSelected". Also create a function in the scope/controller that listens for a ng-change="doChange". In the doChange function, loop through or do a filter on the the items.isSelected==true. And show the submit button if an item exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Directive/Component for each Order item so that you can isolate the scope of each order. Then check for changes for each item.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.orders=[
      {
        id: 1,
        line_items: [
          {
            id: 1,
            "name": "item 1"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            "name": "item 2"
          
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        line_items:[
          {
            id: 3,
            "name": "item 3"
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            "name": "item 4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
});

app.component('order', {
  template: '<h2>Order {{$ctrl.order.id}}</h2><div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.order.line_items"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected" ng-change="$ctrl.doChange()"> {{item.name}}</label></div><div ng-show="$ctrl.showButton"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>',
  bindings: {
    order: '=ngModel',
    
  },
  controller: function() {
    this.showButton = false;
    this.doChange = function(){
      var checkedItems = this.order.line_items.filter( (item)=>{
        return item.isSelected;
      });
      this.showButton = (checkedItems && checkedItems.length>0)
    }
    
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <section class="orders" ng-repeat="order in orders">
        <Order ng-model="order"></Order>
    </section>
    
  </body>

</html>
```